# how to change tableview's cells background dynamically

Tags: javafx

I want to change  tableview's cells background color when their values is empty. Could you help me? thanks.
Below, an overview of my source code, but it doesn't work.

```
public class Cell extends TextFieldTableCell<Itemtest, String>{

    public Cell(StringConverter<String> str){
        super(str);
        this.itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue)->{
                    if(newValue.isEmpty())
                        this.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.RED, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        setText(empty ? null : getString());
        setGraphic(null);           
    }

    private String getString(){
        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't need a cell implementation for this; you can do this entirely in CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your code you set the background to a color, if the item becomes `""`. You never change it back in case the item should change. Also the item being `""` implies that the cell is **not empty**.

Furthermore you have already overwritten the `updateItem` method which is called when the item changed or the cell becomes empty and it should be used instead to update the background.

```
public class Cell extends TextFieldTableCell<Itemtest, String>{

    public Cell(StringConverter<String> str){
        super(str);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        setText(empty ? null : getString());
        setGraphic(null);

        // is this really the check you want?
        if (item != null && item.isEmpty()) {
             this.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.RED, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        } else {
             // change back to empty background
             this.setBackground(Background.EMPTY);
        }
    }

    private String getString(){
        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: I want to do some controls on the values of the table's cells when i click on a button (like ensure that the values are numeric, or are not empty) and change the background color of their cells if these constraints are not respected. How can i do this?

Comment: Do all the `TableCell`s do that check in `updateItem`? Starting with JavaFX 8 update 60, you can use `TableView.refresh()`.

Comment: I use `TableView.refresh()`  inside  `controlButton.setOnAction(ev ->{ ..});` It works. Thanks a lot.